# How do I switch layout when connected to a Bluetooth device in a Handler?

Tags: java, android

So I would like to change the layout once i'm successfully connected to a Bluetooth device. I would like to do this in my Handler, but I don't know how. As you can see in my Handler code below , I've tried this in my `case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:` (this is just copied from BluetoothChat) but I dont know how.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                            mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                            break;
                        case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting…", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.v("Log", "connecting");
                            break;
                        case BTHandler.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case BTHandler.STATE_NONE:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.v("Log", "connected");
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by myself.

```
guiHandler(Constants.CONNECTION_STATUS, Constants.STATE_CONNECTED, "");
```

This is written in my `run` method that's inside a `ConnectThread`.